# Erzählt mir doch nich, dasset nich jeht!

Tags: translation, idiom, colloquial

I have seen this sentence on FB. I looked it up and it turned to be a book title. However, I couldn't understand what it means. *nich* could mean *nicht*, *jeht* could be *geht*?!, *dasset* according to google has to do with cryptocurrency and Bitcoin but I doubt it. It looks more like *dass*.

Is it old German? A regional dialect? What does it mean?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's just an idiom from Berlin and broader counties (Brandenburg), so it's a regional dialect.

> Erzählt mir doch nich, dasset nich jeht!

Translated to regular german would be

> > Sagt mir doch (bitte) nicht, dass das nicht geht (funtktioniert).

English:

> > Please don't tell me that this won't work out.

Comment: Is it pronounced by people like it's written as well? *geht* with *j* instead of *g*?

Comment: @User Yes. Replacing `g` with `j` is usual for the Berlin/Brandenburg idiom specifically. A prominent example is _JWD_ standing for _"janz weit draussen"_ in b4 _"ganz weit draussen"_ in b4 _"from the outer city woods"_.

Comment: @User Pro Tip: If you want to have a bake roll at a bakery in Berlin, order a "Schrippe", "Brötchen" will earn laughter, "Semmel" probably some respect but denied understanding. The Bavarian idiom is still somehow respected there unless H. Seehofer doesn't manage to consume all of that respect for his throws.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, nicht jedes Brötchen ist eine Schrippe.

Comment: @Carsten Da steck' i ned drin. Regionale Bezeichnungen für Backwaren sind eine Wissenschaft für sich (Oder weisst Du genau was der Unterschied von einem "Römer" zu einer "Roggensemmel" ist?) ;-) Das wirklich Schöne zu sehen, ist dass wir so eine Diversität und Vielfalt in unserem Land haben, sprachlich wie kulturell. Ich verstehe nicht warum da nicht noch mehr Kulturen und Sprachen integrierbar sein sollten.

Comment: @Carsten I.e.: _Icke find die CSU und AfD nich so jut, jetze!_

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, das ist ja alles richtig, ich wollte nur sagen, dass man auch in Berlin Brötchen bestellt, wenn man Brötchen möchte. Schrippen sind die mit einem einzelnen Spalt in der Mitte, und sie sind hier der Default. https://www.dwds.de/wb/Schrippe#et-1

Comment: @Carsten Ach ich dachte immer "Brötchen" geht nur in Hannover oder Kiel :D Aber ich habe das Thema ja politisch schon weit über Jebühr überzogen ;-). Die _"Kaisersemmel"_ (mit den 5 Spalten) ist offenbar schon so etwas wie ein Anachronismus.

Comment: I don't think, that *Please don't tell me that this won't work out.* is a propper english translation. It is rather *Don't tell me that this won't work out*. The speaker is not expressing a wish, but rather an expectation in a sense similar to *Don't try to fool me telling me this won't work out.* This is expressed by the *doch*. The *please* is something you just added to the sentence by yourself, it is not part of the german sentence .Hence, I gave -1 here.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach So you have a better proposal for translation?

Comment: Just have a look at my comment or at the other answer.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach So what about writing your own answer?

Comment: There is already a correct answer below.

Comment: I tend to believe there is a tendency on german.stackexchange to prefer longer answers above shorter answers, regardless of their actual quality. This post is an example for that. This answer is longest, highest rated and accepted, even though it's (at least) slightly wrong and misleading: There is no "Please" in the german sentence and the translation lacks to address the "doch" which makes a big part of the meaning of the original sentence. In the meanwhile the correct answer (by @user34825), simply giving the  correct translation is not as complex and thus shorter and less upvoted.

Answer (score 4):

It is a regional dialect. It translates to:

> Erzählt mir doch nicht, dass das nicht geht!

Which means:

> Don't tell me that this is not possible.

Answer (score 2):

> Erzählt mir doch nicht, dass es nicht geht!

- nich=nicht  Das t wird in großen Teilen Deutschlands weg reduziert, manchmal bleibt nur ein "ni" übrig (z.B. Dresden).
- preußisches Dialektgebiet (Berlin, Brandenburg, Sachsen-Anhalt):

  - jeht=geht - "g" in Anfangsstellung wird allgemein zu "j"
  - dasset=dass es

    1. Die zwei Wörter werden in der Umgangssprache mündlich zusammengezogen: dasses (siehe auch isses=ist es / hammses=haben sie es / bistes=bist du es)
    2. aus "s" in Endstellung wird im Dialektgebiet rund um Berlin ein "t" (siehe auch allet=alles)

Comment: Genauer gesagt: gemeingermanisches “t” wird im Oberdeutschen zu /ts/ oder /s/. „Et“ (englisch: „it“) ist die ältere Form.